# Why SSE in rails hang on the connection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server-sent-events

I am reading [this post](https://blog.chumakoff.com/en/posts/rails_sse_rack_hijacking_api) which talks about **SSE connections without blocking server threads** The author is describing how to solve the blocking.

My confusion is If I am closing the stream on server side (with `sse.close`) and on client side (with `source.close()`) why there is problem in the first place? Why the server hangs on the connection?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more helpful to comment on that post and ask this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is not in closing the connection, it's about *when* you are doing it - this happens way later(dozens of seconds, may be even into hours) than for a regular request, which is usually handled below couple of seconds even for the heaviest ones.

For example, let's say (very simplified and approximated):

1. you have 10 threads/workers, no SSE
2. you serve each html page in under 0.1 seconds
3. a user will wait up to a 1 second for page to load before busting in tears and going away from your site
4. the user will then read the page for 9 seconds before requesting next one

this way each thread can serve 10 pages a second, all threads - 100 pages a second, since every user requests at most one per 10 seconds - you can handle **about 1000 users** using your app simultaneously.

Now adding SSE updates to these pages, step by step:

1. first user connects, gets html in 0.1 sec, then one thread is occupied with SSE request for 9 seconds before page reload, and after that reload it will again be locked by the same users' request
2. you have only 9 idle threads
3. second user connects, the same repeats

This way only maximum of **10 users** can be handled by the same system, that's 100x less. And you cannot just increase threads to 1000, because they are not free (memory, scheduler overhead etc.).

The catch is that most of the time most such connections are not doing anything, just waiting for events, so they actually do not need a thread reserved for them. So it's logical to free the thread for other requests without closing the connection, that's what hijack does.

PS. This approach can be taken even further - client live updates connection can be kept open by a process other than rails server (non-ruby and more efficient) while still doing all the events logic in rails. For example with anycable backend for ActionCable you can keep thousands of concurrent connections easily

Comment: Thanks for such details! So just to confirm. When I close the connection on the back-end and front-end, I am not freeing the thread? To add some context. My use case is very simple. I have a form for a post with previewing feature. The preview hits the server for heavy data compilation. I am opening the connection just when someone clicks preview btn, establish the eventSource, get the data, then close.

Comment: When connection is closed - you are freeing it indeed, but anyway long requests to rails server are evil and can lock up your server. If these are rare and you do not expect more than 1-2 in parallel - you can get away with current setup, otherwise it's better to handle them in background jobs with progress delivered via anycable (users will see that their job is waiting to start, then progress etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You execute `sse.close` after all communication with the client via SSE is finished (after all heavy work is done and all results are sent to the client).
But until then the Rails (Puma) thread is occupied.

The approach described in the post shows how you can free Rails (Puma) threads immediately and keep doing your job while still being connecting with the client.

Using Rack Hijacking API you can free Rails (Puma) threads immediately, right after the server receives a request and before you actually close the SSE connection executing `sse.close`.